# Array difference by explicitly specified method or block

Tags: ruby

If I have Arrays `a` and `b`, the expression `a-b` returns an Array with all those elements in `a` which are not in `b`. "Not in" means unequality (`!=`) here.

In my case, both arrays only contain elements of the same type (or, from the ducktyping perspective, only elements which understand a "equality" method `f`).
Is there an easy way to specify this `f` as a criterium of equality, in a similar way I can provide my own comparator when doing `sort`? Currently, I implemented this explicitly :

```
# Get the difference a-b, based on 'f':
a.select { |ael| b.all? {|bel| ael.f != bel.f} }
```

This works, but I wonder if there is an easier way.

**UPDATE**: From the comments to this question, I get the impression, that a concrete example would be appreciated. So, here we go:

```
class Dummy; end

# Create an Array of Dummy objects.
a = Array.new(99) { Dummy.new }

# Pick some of them at random
b = Array.new(10) { a.sample }

# Now I want to get those elements from a, which are not in b.
diff = a.select { |ael| b.all? {|bel| ael.object_id != bel.object_id} }
```

Of course in this case, I could also have said `! ael eql? bel`, but in my general solution, this is not the case.

Comment: Hm.. can I see some of the data you're trying to work with? Are all A's F's the same?

Comment: @chad_: Actually the elements in my  `a ` and  `b` are quite complex classes. That's why I left them out. If you need a concrete example, think of `f` simply as being the method `object_id`. Actually, in an early version of my program, I did have `object_id` here,only that I switched now to something different, which suits me better.

Comment: You could create a wrapper that delegates `<=>`, `eql?` and `hash` to the respective method's result. Then `map` all objects to the wrapper, perform the calculation you want (difference / sorting) on the wrappers, and unwrap afterwards.

Comment: You could also override == in your object, then just get the --intersection of the arrays via &-- sorry,  I misread it.. but - will work properly if you override ==

Comment: @Stefan: This would be equivalent to redefining `<=>` and including `comparable` in my class, isn't it? I would consider it even worse to redefine the semantics of this class just because at one place, I need to calculate the difference.

Comment: @chad_ : This would spoil every other use of `==` in the code. I am looking for a solution where I can describe the behaviour just for this single invocation; i.e. in a block. If my current approach wouldn't look so clumsy, I would already be satisfied with it.

Comment: well, it would only impact equality for that particular object, but I get what you're saying.

Comment: (I meant to override == inside the class for the objects in the array...)

Comment: @user1934428 no, you'd add the wrapper for sorting / diffing, then get rid of it afterwards. Your objects would stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" object equality for e.g. Hashes and set operations on Arrays (such as the `-` operation) uses the output of the [`Object#hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-hash) method of the contained objects along with the semantics of the `a.eql?(b)` comparison.

This can be used to to improve performance. Ruby assumes here that two objects are `eql?` if the return value of their respective `hash` methods is the same (and consequently, assumes that two objects returning different `hash` values to not be `eql?`).

For a normal `a - b` operation, this can thus be used to first calculate the `hash` value of each object once and then only compare those values. This is quite fast.

Now, if you have a custom equality, your best bet would be to overwrite the object's `hash` methods so that they return suitable values for those semantics.

A common approach is to build an array containing all data taking part of the object's identity and getting its hash, e.g.

```
class MyObject
  #...
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar 

  def hash
    [self.class, foo, bar].hash
  end
end
```

In your object's `hash` method, you would than include all data that is currently considered by your `f` comparison method. Instead of actually using `f` then, you are using the default semantics of all Ruby objects and again can achieve quick set operations with your objects.

If however this is not feasible (e.g. because you need different equality semantics based on use-case), you could emulate what ruby does on your own.

With your `f` method, you could then perform your set operation as follows:

```
def f_difference(a, b)
  a_map = a.each_with_object({}) do |a_el, hash|
    hash[a_el.f] = a_el
  end

  b.each do |b_el|
    a_map.delete b_el.f
  end

  a_map.values
end
```

With this approach, you only need to calculate the `f` value of each of your objects once. We first build a hash map with all `f` values and elements from `a` and remove the matching elements from `b` according to their `f` values. The remaining values are the result.

This approach saves you from having to loop over `b` for each object in `a` which can be slow of you have a lot of objects. If however you only have a few objects on each of your arrays, your original approach should already be fine.

Let's have a look at a benchmark whee I use the standard `hash` method in place of your custom `f` to have a comparable result.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

def question_diff(a, b)
  a.select { |ael| b.all? {|bel| ael.hash != bel.hash} }
end

def answer_diff(a, b)
  a_map = a.each_with_object({}) do |a_el, hash|
    hash[a_el.hash] = a_el
  end

  b.each do |b_el|
    a_map.delete b_el.hash
  end

  a_map.values
end

A = Array.new(100) { rand(10_000) }
B = Array.new(10) { A.sample }

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("question") { question_diff(A, B) }
  x.report("answer") { answer_diff(A, B) }

  x.compare!
end
```

With Ruby 2.7.1, I get the following result on my machine, showing that the original approach from the question is about 5.9 times slower than the optimized version from my answer:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
            question     1.304k i/100ms
              answer     7.504k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
            question     12.779k (± 2.0%) i/s -     63.896k in   5.002006s
              answer     74.898k (± 3.3%) i/s -    375.200k in   5.015239s

Comparison:
              answer:    74898.0 i/s
            question:    12779.3 i/s - 5.86x  (± 0.00) slower
```

Comment: Why not use `f` directly? (1) create a hash `h` which maps `ael.f` to `ael` (2) traverse `b` and delete `bel.f` from `h` (3) return `h.values`.

Comment: I assumed that OP's original `f` method only compares values. From your description, it reads as if you assume that `f` essentially returns a value like the one I built with `f_hash`. If that would be the case, OP can use their `f` method exactly like I used `f_hash` in my answer. The final hash comparison is then rather quick in any case. I have still edited my answer with your approach which is indeed a tiny bit faster than my original approach. It still assumes a suitable `f_hash` method though.

Comment: The OP's example contains `ael.f != bel.f` – that looks like a static value.

Comment: Hmmm, and now that I read the question again, `f` indeed is supposed to work as my `f_hash` method . Thus, we can indeed use it directly...

Comment: Okay, edited again given this new information. The general approach is the same :)  Maybe I should indeed read the actual question rather than to assume an even more interesting question :)

Comment: Are hypothetical problems off-topic? If not, you could just post the more interesting variant as a new question :-)

Comment: @HolgerJust : To be honest, I find your approach interesting, but it doesn't look simpler and easier to understand than the solution I'm using now. I would have to benchmark it to see whether it is faster, but you have to construct an auxiliary hash, so I at least don't find it obviously faster.

Comment: @user1934428 Well, the big O complexity of your original solution is much worse, namely `O(n²)` rather than `O(2n)` of my answer. With your original solution, you are looping through your `b` array `a.size` times. If you have 100 elements in each array, you would thus have up to 10_000 comparisons. With the solution in my answer, you would only have up 200 operations, that is, you would only have to calculate `f` exactly once for each element. Also, hashes are rather cheap...

Comment: @HolgerJust : Good point! Even though I hadn't expected a Hash to be **that** cheap. For each access, you have to calculate the hashing function to locate the respective entry, and if you have a collision (several objects mapping to the same hash value), Ruby has to do some disambiguation, which probably means a sequential search of the colliding elements. Perhaps I really should do some benchmarks, to get a feeling for the actual performance.

Comment: @user1934428 See the latest edit to my answer where I have added an actual benchmark.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the effort. I see that, in particular for large data, it's worth to pay attention to the performance difference. For small data sets, readability is more important, and in particular for this problem, it seems to me highly subjective which version is easier to understand and to maintain.